# c++ skipping the if and for loops?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am writing a program that would accept a file from users and do some calculations based on the data in the file. The first line contains the right answers for a multiple answer test (with 6 questions). The second line contains student ID, the third line contains student answers, the fourth line contains a new student Id, followed by the answers, etc.

I need to go through the file, choose the right answers and compare student answers to them. Then, for each student, display student ID, the number of rights, wrongs, and blanks (?) for each question.

This is my code below and I am stuck because the program is skipping the loops and I do not know what to do?

```
#include <iostream>  // include to use cin and/or cout
#include <fstream>   // include to use ifstream
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int id, c, w, mis, s, numberL;
string answer, a, correct;
string info[numberL];
char question [] = {'?'};
cout << " enter file " << endl;
cin >> a;
ifstream myfile(a.c_str());
myfile >> answer;  
s = 0;
while (s <= numberL)
{
  myfile >> info[s];
  s++;
}
for (int i =3; i < numberL; i = i+2)
{
  if ( numberL == answer[1])
  {
     c = c+1;
  }
  if ( numberL == question [1])
  {
     mis = mis+1;
  }     
  if ( numberL != answer [1] || numberL != question [1] )
  {
     w = w+1;
  }
}
printf("Student #    1    2    3   4   5   6  Mark    %\n");
cout << c << endl;
cout << w << endl;
cout << mis << endl;
cout << answer ; 
}
```

The data in the .txt file is this:

```
AACBEE
1093345
BADBEE
1234567
ACCBEE
8123345
BAC?BE
1234566
A?B?EE
```

Comment: which loop it skips?

Comment: Do you know that your program never assigns a value to `numberL`, don't you?

Comment: `while (s <= numberL)` numberL has no value

Comment: How do I get it to assign a value to it? I tried myfile >> info[numberL]; but I still have the same problem?

Comment: It stops at the while loop @DimChtz

Comment: yes, numberL has no value thats why

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile: "error: variable length array `string info[numberL];`"

Comment: @zenith it actually compiles but skips all loops... I am using c++ ..

Comment: Assign a value to `numberL` before the while loop and `string info[numberL];` and consider using a vector instead of string array

Comment: and change `while (s <= numberL)` to `while (s < numberL)` because when `s == numberL` you will try to access `info[s]` which means `info[numberL]` this is wrong

Comment: Use a debugger.  Execute the statements one at a time, *watching* values of variables. This is what you should do next.

Comment: The debugger won't help much after segfault in while loop. It's clear that author doesn't have any skill for C/C++ debugger, he needs to understand basic C programming concepts like declaration, assignment, array..

Answer (score 1):

just looking at this code

```
int id, c, w, mis, s, numberL;
string answer, a, correct;
string info[numberL];
```

What - in your mind - does numberL contain? The number of lines in the file? (I am guessing here) The number of Lessons? Whatever it is supposed to be you need to set it. Look at the third line - you are telling the compiler to allocate that many lines - it doesnt know how many lines you mean. The loops get equally confused

This is not a language question it is a program design question - what does numberL mean?

Answer (score -1):

The remarks that this code shouldn't compile are not right. It depends on compiler options. Usually it will. Based on the question the code was compiled and executed.
What happened is that standard C some not busy addresses to newly declared integers. This means that your integers will have **random values**.

```
int id, c, w, mis, s, numberL;
cout << id << " "<< c <<" "<< w <<" "<< mis <<" "<< s <<" "<< numberL<<"\n";
```

on my computer at Thursday evening after restroom:

```
4199344 0 4199437 0 2 32765
```

numberL = 32765 now.

```
while (s <= numberL) {    myfile >> info[s];   s++;  }
```

goes 32765 times. It would mess up 32765 bytes of memory (if char == byte on your machine, since str[i] refers to **i**th char after begin of string) starting from some *initially* unbusy address happened to be assigned to var **info**, if not myfile length and smart << implementation. I'm unsure if it actually does sometimes. May or may not cause error(segfault)

```
for (int i =3; i < numberL; i = i+2)
```

checks 3 < 32765. True. works ~16381 times. True(99.9999..%) in

```
if ( numberL != answer [1] || numberL != question [1] )
{
  w = w+1;
}
```

which modifies "initial" value of w = 4199437 into smth like 425....

program output(with input 'a'):

```
4199344 0 4199437 0 2 32765

enter file 
a
Student #    1    2    3   4   5   6  Mark    %
0
4215818
0
```

You don't see 4th line because

> string answer, a, incorrect;

defaults to ""  - empty string and I had no file to input.